# MongoDB clusterMonitor role without giving permissions to see all the databases

Tags: mongodb, privileges

I use recently mongodb and I am experimenting with the management of users and roles.
I was trying to create a role that could only read a specific database but also see the cluster performance with MongoDB compass, but to do that I have to create it in the admin database, and by doing so the user gets permission to see all the databases

How I create the user:

```
> use admin

> db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'username',
    pwd: '***',
    roles: [
        { role: "clusterMonitor", db: "admin" },
        { role: "read", db: "MyDatabase"}
      ]
  }
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display the performance"? Revoke `clusterMonitor` role.

Comment: Oh, my bad, *see the performance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [user-defined role](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#mongodb-method-db.createRole) based on [clusterMonitor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-clusterMonitor) that doesn't include `listDatabases` and any other actions that you do not desire.